# a number of / the number of

Tags: determiners, quantifiers

I have a question.

I know 'a number of ' means 'a lot', and 'the number of' means 'the quantity of'.

so.. I say, 'a number of apples.' and then, I want to repeat the phrase 'a number of apples' wherein the apples are the same apples.

Then should I say 'a number of the apples' or "the number of the apples.'

I mean, when repeating the same thing, definite article is used, like an apple-> the apple.

should I put 'the' in front of 'apples'? or should I change 'a' to 'the'?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This would be easier to answer this if you could write some whole example sentences, rather than bits and pieces, with details about the parts you are not clear about.

Comment: A number of doesn't mean a lot of. It means several, various, a few, or some. The question is not clear at all.

Comment: *a number of **the** apples* -I first thought you are giving some number (-say 3832) to the box of apples!*

Answer (score 3):

***A*** number of apples means an **indefinite** quantity of apples, roughly equivalent to *quite a few apples* or *several apples*.

> I have a number of apples in this bag.

***The*** number of apples, however, means a **definite** quantity of apples: the exact number of apples under discussion.

> The number of apples in this bag is seven.

In both,  the article (*a* or *the*) refers to *number*, not to *apples*; but while ***a***-number-of acts is a multiword quantifier which acts as a determiner on apples, ***the***-number is a standalone noun phrase which is modified by the preposition phrase *of apples*.

Consequently, you cannot treat the two expressions as 'co-referential' like bare *a* and *the*, which can be used as determiners of the same entity at different stages of a discourse, because only one of them is used as a determiner. Thus, although these two pairs of statements work well enough:

> I have **an** apple in this bag. <sup>ok</sup>**The** apple is a Red Delicious.
>      and
>   I have **seven** apples in this bag. <sup>ok</sup>**The** seven apples are all Red Delicious.

... this pair of statements is impossible:

> I have **a number of** apples in this bag. <sup>∗</sup>**The** number of apples are all Red Delicious.

If you want to do something like this, you have to use some other expression instead of *a number of*:

> I have **several** apples in this bag. <sup>ok</sup>**The** several apples are all Red Delicious.

---

<sup>∗</sup> <sub>marks an utterance as ungrammatical</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 'a number of apples' to mean 'a certain quantity of apples', then you can later refer to them as *those apples*.  For example

Jane:  There were a number of apples on the table this morning.
Charlie: I didn't see any apples.
Jane:   I guess someone must have come along and taken those apples.

Comment: This does not answer the question: "Then should I say 'a number of the apples' or "the number of the apples.'" Also see the questions' title.

Comment: @δοῦλος You don't say either.  Either would sound either awkward or confusing.